# SQL Azure Create Rule walkaround to use UserDefinedDataType

Tags: azure-sql-database, user-defined-types

CREATE RULE is not supported on SQL AZURE. Is there a walkaround ?

```
CREATE RULE [dbo].[Rule1] AS
@variable IS NOT NULL
```

I wanna use UserDefinedDataType supported in azure, to create strong type like email type, percentage type and so on. BUT without rules it's like almost useless...
Any solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined rules are currently not supported on v1 servers. However, if you upgrade your server to the latest SQL Database v12 update then CREATE RULE & many other SQL Server features are available.

See links below:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-upgrade/

Comment: thanks a lot, I don't find where it's writing in your link but I trust you. So I will upgrade tomorrow.